# Имена параметров конструктора

Tags: perl

**UPD**

Таки преодолев "дис-чего-то там", подобрал словечки. И их даже стало больше. Основа осталась та же, но кое-что уточнилось, кое-что добавилось. Результат можно посмотреть [здесь](http://ato.su/asmtidy/). На самом деле эта утилита работает локально, как довесок к редактору исходников. В онлайне просто висит тот же класс, для тестов. B всё равно хотелось бы комментариев: доступным ли языком сделаны пояснения? Naming conventions в этой области нет (ни в perltidy, ни в indent, ни в phptidy ... etc), поэтому в имена параметров я и не стал упираться.

**OLD**

Как-то от нечего делать набросал на коленке форматирование ассемблерных исходников (intel, тренировался на nasm). Делалось для себя, поэтому с осмысленными именами параметров не заморачивался. Но подумалось: а вдруг? И понял, что имена этих самых параметров вряд ли кому-то будут понятны :) Отсюда **вопрос: как их обозвать?** Сейчас вызов конструктора выглядит так (параметры по умолчанию):

```
my $tidy = new asmtidy( left=>4, right=>1, comma=>0, cmt=>undef, cmt_tail=>1 );
```

И их пояснение, что именно хотелось бы переобозвать:

1) условно **left => N**

Отступ в пробелах от левого края:

```
label:
    mov eax,ebx     ; left => 4
      xchg eax,ebx  ; left => 6
```

2) условно **comma => N**

Отступы между запятой и вторым операндом, по умолчанию 0:

```
    mov eax,ebx     ; comma => 0
    xchg eax, ebx   ; comma => 1
```

3) условно **cmt_tail => N**

Отступ между комментарием в хвосте строки и командами (выравнивается по самой длинной строке кода с комментарием):

```
mov eax,ebx                ; cmt_tail => 1
lea edi,[esi+eax+12345678] ; cmt_tail => 1

mov eax,ebx                   ; cmt_tail => 4
lea edi,[esi+eax+12345678]    ; cmt_tail => 4
```

Дальше пошла сложная логика :)

4) условно **cmt => 'align'**

Что делать с полнострочными комментариями, которые не начинаются с первой позиции строки. Прижимать к левому краю или выравнивать по коду. Видимо, нужно "булевское" название, так как *пока(?)* значение да/нет.

Было:

```
      ; комментарий
  ; комментарий
    add eax,[edx]
```

Станет:

```
; комментарий
; комментарий
    add eax,[edx] ; cmt => ?

    ; комментарий
    ; комментарий
    add eax,[edx] ; cmt => 'align'
```

5) и самое сложное, условно **right => N | 'tabN'**

Что делать после инструкции при наличии операндов. Или вставлять **N** пробелов:

```
lea eax,[edi]    ; right => 1
lea    eax,[edi] ; right => 4
```

Или выравнивать по *левому* краю инструкции, вставляя необходимое количество пробелов до **N**. Если длина инструкции больше N - игнорировать.

```
dec  ebx        ; right => 'tab5'
movzx esi,al    ; игнорируем

dec    ebx        ; right => 'tab7'
movzx  esi,al     ; right => 'tab7'
punpckldq mm1,mm2 ; игнорируем
```

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите названия из утилиты [`perltidy`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perltidy).

Comment: Там километровые имена оправданы, только для форматирования комментариев больше 20 параметров. Не хотелось бы лепить что-то вроде `closing_side_comments_balanced` или `outdent_static_block_comments`,  для всего двух опций это кажется избыточным.

Comment: P.S. Проблема даже не в длине - я просто не могу подобрать слова для их описания :)